# Merging table data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, import-from-csv

I have an LDAP CSV file that is imported nightly and dumped into my MYSQL database.  It has about 70000 employee records.

Included in that is empl#, email, group, supervisor, etc.

I have reports that are being generated from various web sites.  We are dumping these reports in the database once a month.  These reports usually have empl#, email, hits, logins, whatever...

My goal is to combine the report data and add in things like group, supervisor, etc based on empl#...  Speed is a big concern because of the size of the database and number of users.

At first I thought of making a simple left join (given that report data is left - and that all people in the report may not be an employee).  However the problem with that is that it does not take a snapshot in time.  If report data from 6 months ago is viewed I don't want it mixed with current employee data - I want it to stay a snapshot in time.

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a **date** column of some kind in both sets of data on which to join.  Once you have that, you can simply put a condition that establishes the snapshot in the WHERE that limits the selection.

Comment: I have that with employee #.  Not sure what else you are saying here.

Comment: Changed "data" to "date."  You need a column on which to limit the scope based on the time.